# how to print the html file content as a body of the email message using python?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, email, smtp

```
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('C:\Users\top\UDI\New folder'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.html'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        filename = root.rstrip(os.sep) + os.sep+ filename
        #print filename

        fromaddress = 'ucm_embed_test'
        toaddress = "hetappa@ace.com, hepa@gmail.com"
        text = "Test is Parsed"

        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['From'] =fromaddress
        msg['To'] = toaddress
        msg['Subject'] = text

        print "Sending mail"
        ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
        if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
            ctype = "application/octet-stream"
        maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/", 1)

        with open(filename) as fp:
            attachment = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
        attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment",\
                              filename=os.path.basename(filename))

        msg.attach(MIMEText(open(filename).read(), "text/html"))
        server = smtplib.SMTP('eu-smtp.nuae.com')
        server.ehlo()
        #server.starttls()
        #server.login(username,password)
        server.sendmail(fromaddress,toaddress.split(','),msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
```

I am reading a .html file and later sending it as an email to the respective person. But the message body appeared in the email is in the form of html tags. how to represent my answers as the characters in the message body. Can someone help me in this ?

Comment: Attach as `html ` document ! Or use `html.escape` but need convert before reading.

Comment: thanks. I solved it.